# Invalid SQL statement; expected "DELETE"

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following code in MS Access:

```
Set rs = con.Execute

(SELECT PO_Number, PR_Number, PO_Creator_Number, PO_Creator_Name, PR_Creator_Number, PR_Creator_Name, 
   (CASE WHEN PO_Creator_Region <> "'IL'"
   THEN
   ((DATEDIFF(dd, PR_Creation_Date, PR_Approval_Date)+1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, PR_Creation_Date, PR_Approval_Date)*2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PR_Creation_Date) = "'Sunday'" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PR_Approval_Date) = "'Saturday'" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)),
                    ELSE
                     ((DATEDIFF(dd, PR_Creation_Date, PR_Approval_Date)+1)
                    -(DATEDIFF(wk, PR_Creation_Date, PR_Approval_Date)*2)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PR_Creation_Date) = "'Friday'" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                    -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, PR_Approval_Date) = "'Saturday'" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))
                    END) AS PR_Cycle_Time  

FROM PO_PR_INFO_TBL

WHERE PR_Creation_Date ='" & txtnumb & "'",
         PR_Approval_Date = '" & txtnumb & "'",
         PO_Creation_Date ='" & txtnumb & "'"

GROUP BY PO_Number, PR_Number, PO_Creator_Number, PO_Creator_Name,   PR_Creator_Number, PR_Creator_Name)
```

Then MS Access gives me an error message saying

> Invalid SQL Statement; expected "DELETE", "INSERT", "PROCEDURE",
>   "SELECT", or "UPDATE"

Can anyone help me on solving this issue?

Comment: remove the line with SET

Comment: You are conflating VBA and SQL. What code is this? I am thinking you placed it in query window expecting only SQL since VBA would yell with red highlights at the compiled syntax issues as code shows no line breaks or quotations around literals.

Comment: Thank you for looking at my question! Yes I put it in SQL window and hoped to get the SQL results only since I don't really have experiences in VBA...

Comment: The code is completely wrong. You need to generate SQL text using VBA first, then create a query and assign this text to SQL property of query or use for opening a recordset. Also SQL syntax not supported by Access SQL unless you are trying to make pass-through query to external SQL server. In this case you need to indicate this explicitly and add a tag of your SQL server to the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're lucky replacing the `set...` line with `SELECT * FROM(` and adding `)` at the very end could do the trick.

But this only aims for a quick and dirty solution as the query seems not exactly well formed.